# How to solve this 'Error Refreshing Makefiles'?

Tags: makefile, omnet++, veins, sumo

When I click on **Run** on my VeinsTutorial (the one that Christoph Sommer made and you might be familiar with it), I get error shown below. Do you have any idea? I really need to get over this error.

```
Error refreshing Makefiles 
Reason: 
you have both .cc and .cpp files -- specify -e cc or -e cpp option to select which set of files to use

make MODE=release all 
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
'
'Simulation terminated with exit code: 1

<!> Error: NED type 'veinstutorial.src.TutorialAppl' could not be fully resolved due to a missing base type or interface, at C:\Users\konra\git\repository\carlogicapi-master\carlogicapi-master\tutorials\VeinsTutorial\src\TutorialAppl.ned:19


End.
```

This is the MAKEFILES FILE where I should change something, but I cannot see where it should be changed.

````
#
# OMNeT++/OMNEST Makefile for $(LIB_PREFIX)veins
#
# This file was generated with the command:
#  opp_makemake --make-so -f --deep -o veins -O out -pVEINS -I. -I.
#

# Name of target to be created (-o option)
TARGET = $(LIB_PREFIX)veins$(D)$(SHARED_LIB_SUFFIX)
TARGET_DIR = .

# C++ include paths (with -I)
INCLUDE_PATH = -I. -I.

# Additional object and library files to link with
EXTRA_OBJS =

# Additional libraries (-L, -l options)
LIBS =

# Output directory
PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR = ../out
PROJECTRELATIVE_PATH = src
O = $(PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR)/$(CONFIGNAME)/$(PROJECTRELATIVE_PATH)

# Object files for local .cc, .msg and .sm files
OBJS = \
    $O/veins/base/connectionManager/BaseConnectionManager.o \
    $O/veins/base/connectionManager/ChannelAccess.o \
    $O/veins/base/connectionManager/ConnectionManager.o \
    $O/veins/base/connectionManager/NicEntryDebug.o \
    $O/veins/base/connectionManager/NicEntryDirect.o \
    $O/veins/base/modules/BaseApplLayer.o \
    $O/veins/base/modules/BaseBattery.o \
    $O/veins/base/modules/BaseLayer.o \
    $O/veins/base/modules/BaseMacLayer.o \
    $O/veins/base/modules/BaseMobility.o \
    $O/veins/base/modules/BaseModule.o \
    $O/veins/base/modules/BaseWorldUtility.o \
    $O/veins/base/modules/BatteryAccess.o \
    $O/veins/base/phyLayer/Antenna.o \
    $O/veins/base/phyLayer/BaseDecider.o \
    $O/veins/base/phyLayer/BasePhyLayer.o \
    $O/veins/base/phyLayer/ChannelInfo.o \
    $O/veins/base/phyLayer/Decider.o \
    $O/veins/base/phyLayer/PhyUtils.o \
    $O/veins/base/toolbox/Signal.o \
    $O/veins/base/toolbox/SignalUtils.o \
    $O/veins/base/toolbox/Spectrum.o \
    $O/veins/base/utils/Coord.o \
    $O/veins/base/utils/Heading.o \
    $O/veins/base/utils/NetwToMacControlInfo.o \
    $O/veins/base/utils/SimpleAddress.o \
    $O/veins/base/utils/winsupport.o \
    $O/veins/modules/analogueModel/BreakpointPathlossModel.o \
    $O/veins/modules/analogueModel/NakagamiFading.o \
    $O/veins/modules/analogueModel/PERModel.o \
    $O/veins/modules/analogueModel/SimpleObstacleShadowing.o \
    $O/veins/modules/analogueModel/SimplePathlossModel.o \
    $O/veins/modules/analogueModel/TwoRayInterferenceModel.o \
    $O/veins/modules/analogueModel/VehicleObstacleShadowing.o \
    $O/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayer.o \
    $O/veins/modules/application/traci/MyVeinsApp.o \
    $O/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.o \
    $O/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemoRSU11p.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/LinearMobility.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIBuffer.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIColor.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICoordinateTransformation.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCILauncher.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIRegionOfInterest.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScreenRecorder.o \
    $O/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIVehicleInserter.o \
    $O/veins/modules/obstacle/MobileHostObstacle.o \
    $O/veins/modules/obstacle/Obstacle.o \
    $O/veins/modules/obstacle/ObstacleControl.o \
    $O/veins/modules/obstacle/VehicleObstacleControl.o \
    $O/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211p.o \
    $O/veins/modules/phy/NistErrorRate.o \
    $O/veins/modules/phy/PhyLayer80211p.o \
    $O/veins/modules/phy/SampledAntenna1D.o \
    $O/veins/modules/utility/BBoxLookup.o \
    $O/veins/modules/utility/HasLogProxy.o \
    $O/veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.o \
    $O/veins/modules/world/annotations/AnnotationDummy.o \
    $O/veins/modules/world/annotations/AnnotationManager.o \
    $O/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/TraCITrafficLightInterface.o \
    $O/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/TraCITrafficLightProgram.o \
    $O/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/logics/TraCITrafficLightAbstractLogic.o \
    $O/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/logics/TraCITrafficLightSimpleLogic.o \
    $O/veins/base/messages/AirFrame_m.o \
    $O/veins/base/messages/BorderMsg_m.o \
    $O/veins/base/messages/MacPkt_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11pMessage_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/AckTimeOutMessage_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/AirFrame11p_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/BaseFrame1609_4_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/DemoSafetyMessage_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/DemoServiceAdvertisement_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/Mac80211Ack_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/Mac80211Pkt_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/PhyControlMessage_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/TraCITrafficLightMessage_m.o \
    $O/veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage_m.o

# Message files
MSGFILES = \
    veins/base/messages/AirFrame.msg \
    veins/base/messages/BorderMsg.msg \
    veins/base/messages/MacPkt.msg \
    veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11pMessage.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/AckTimeOutMessage.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/AirFrame11p.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/BaseFrame1609_4.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/DemoSafetyMessage.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/DemoServiceAdvertisement.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/Mac80211Ack.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/Mac80211Pkt.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/PhyControlMessage.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/TraCITrafficLightMessage.msg \
    veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg

# SM files
SMFILES =

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Pull in OMNeT++ configuration (Makefile.inc)

ifneq ("$(OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE)","")
CONFIGFILE = $(OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE)
else
ifneq ("$(OMNETPP_ROOT)","")
CONFIGFILE = $(OMNETPP_ROOT)/Makefile.inc
else
CONFIGFILE = $(shell opp_configfilepath)
endif
endif

ifeq ("$(wildcard $(CONFIGFILE))","")
$(error Config file '$(CONFIGFILE)' does not exist -- add the OMNeT++ bin directory to the path so that opp_configfilepath can be found, or set the OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE variable to point to Makefile.inc)
endif

include $(CONFIGFILE)

# Simulation kernel and user interface libraries
OMNETPP_LIBS = -loppenvir$D $(KERNEL_LIBS) $(SYS_LIBS)

COPTS = $(CFLAGS) $(IMPORT_DEFINES) -DVEINS_EXPORT $(INCLUDE_PATH) -I$(OMNETPP_INCL_DIR)
MSGCOPTS = $(INCLUDE_PATH) -PVEINS_API
SMCOPTS =

# we want to recompile everything if COPTS changes,
# so we store COPTS into $COPTS_FILE and have object
# files depend on it (except when "make depend" was called)
COPTS_FILE = $O/.last-copts
ifneq ("$(COPTS)","$(shell cat $(COPTS_FILE) 2>/dev/null || echo '')")
$(shell $(MKPATH) "$O" && echo "$(COPTS)" >$(COPTS_FILE))
endif

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# User-supplied makefile fragment(s)
# >>>
# inserted from file 'makefrag':

#
# Copyright (C) 2017 Rudolf Hornig <rudi@omnetpp.org>
#
# Documentation for these modules is at http://veins.car2x.org/
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
#

#
# on windows we have to link with the ws2_32 (winsock2) library as it is no longer added to the omnetpp system libraries by default (as of OMNeT++ 5.1)
# copied from INET Framework (inet-3.6.0) makefrag
#
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),win32.x86_64)
  LIBS += -lws2_32
  DEFINES += -DVEINS_EXPORT
  ENABLE_AUTO_IMPORT=-Wl,--enable-auto-import
  LDFLAGS := $(filter-out $(ENABLE_AUTO_IMPORT), $(LDFLAGS))
endif

# <<<
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Main target
all: $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)

$(TARGET_DIR)/% :: $O/%
    @mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)
    $(Q)$(LN) $< $@
ifeq ($(TOOLCHAIN_NAME),clangc2)
    $(Q)-$(LN) $(<:%.dll=%.lib) $(@:%.dll=%.lib)
endif

$O/$(TARGET): $(OBJS)  $(wildcard $(EXTRA_OBJS)) Makefile $(CONFIGFILE)
    @$(MKPATH) $O
    @echo Creating shared library: $@
    $(Q)echo >.tmp$$$$ $(OBJS) $(EXTRA_OBJS) && $(AR) .tmplib$$$$ @.tmp$$$$ && $(SHLIB_LD) -o $O/$(TARGET) $(AS_NEEDED_OFF) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_ON) .tmplib$$$$ $(LIBS) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_OFF) $(OMNETPP_LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) && rm .tmp$$$$ && rm .tmplib$$$$
    $(Q)$(SHLIB_POSTPROCESS) $O/$(TARGET)

.PHONY: all clean cleanall depend msgheaders smheaders

.SUFFIXES: .cc

$O/%.o: %.cc $(COPTS_FILE) | msgheaders smheaders
    @$(MKPATH) $(dir $@)
    $(qecho) "$<"
    $(Q)$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(COPTS) -o $@ $<

%_m.cc %_m.h: %.msg
    $(qecho) MSGC: $<
    $(Q)$(MSGC) -s _m.cc -MD -MP -MF $O/$(basename $<)_m.h.d $(MSGCOPTS) $?

%_sm.cc %_sm.h: %.sm
    $(qecho) SMC: $<
    $(Q)$(SMC) -c++ -suffix cc $(SMCOPTS) $?

msgheaders: $(MSGFILES:.msg=_m.h)

smheaders: $(SMFILES:.sm=_sm.h)

clean:
    $(qecho) Cleaning $(TARGET)
    $(Q)-rm -rf $O
    $(Q)-rm -f $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)
    $(Q)-rm -f $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET:%.dll=%.lib)
    $(Q)-rm -f $(call opp_rwildcard, . , *_m.cc *_m.h *_sm.cc *_sm.h)

cleanall:
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -s clean MODE=release
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -s clean MODE=debug
    $(Q)-rm -rf $(PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR)

# include all dependencies
-include $(OBJS:%=%.d) $(MSGFILES:%.msg=$O/%_m.h.d) ```
````

Comment: Did you read the "Reason:" part?

Comment: Yes I did , but i was not able to change it, would you know how to do it? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this platform but even those who are would probably need to see the offending input file and understand what you are trying to accomplish with it.

Comment: If the question is essentially about failure of a program / script that is a black box to you, then it is off-topic here.  You should instead seek support from the author, maintainer, user group, or other application-specific support resource.

Comment: When you say, you saw “reason: you have both .cc and .cpp files”, but you don’t know how to change it: are you referring to not knowing how to rename files? Or to not knowing how to convince OMNeT++ to be okay with mixing file extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to change the extension of the TutorialAppl.cpp to CC.

I guess sometimes we look for the difficult way to solve problems and it is actually the easy way you have to take :)

Thanks for your attention.